# Javascript for data summarizing and manipulation

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and unsure of the typical approach to manipulating data for display in charts. I have a local csv file that would need to be aggregated/summarized before showing in a chart. I can bring the data in using the AnyChart Data Loader but I'm wondering if Javascript is typically used to pre-process the data?

Or is it more common to do the pre-processing before Javascripts loads the data (i.e. use Python to do all manipulations for plotting)?

If Javascript is used, what libraries should I start looking at to do the pre-processing?

Comment: If the amount of data is not too much (would not make much sense to have the client request X megabytes of CSV data, that then get crunched down to three numbers or something), and you are not worried about exposing any of the original data, then processing this on the client side would be fine, per se. (Asking us for any library recommendations is off-topic here though.)

Comment: Thanks - the csv should remain <1MB and I would just need to make 3-4 different aggregations (count by day, count by user, etc). Data is freely available and can be exposed.